# React-Native/Firebase: Malformed calls from JS: field sizes are different

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication

I'm trying to authorise users using the Firebase Authentication platform through React-Native. The following code creates a very crude login/sign up page.

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { View, Button, TextInput, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import auth from '@react-native-firebase/auth';

export default function Login() {

    const [email, onChangeEmail] = useState("");
    const [password, onChangePassword] = useState("");

    const signupFn = () => {
        auth()
  .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
  .then(() => {
    console.log('User account created & signed in!');
  })
  .catch(error => {
    if (error.code === 'auth/email-already-in-use') {
      console.log('That email address is already in use!');
    }

    if (error.code === 'auth/invalid-email') {
      console.log('That email address is invalid!');
    }

    console.error(error);
  });
    }

    const loginFn = () => {
        auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
  .then(() => {
    console.log('User account created & signed in!');
  })
  .catch(error => console.log(error))
    }

    return (
        <View style={styles.wrapper}>
            <TextInput placeholder="Email address" onChange={onChangeEmail}/>
            <TextInput placeholder="Password" secureTextEntry={true} onChange={onChangePassword}/>
            <Button title="signup" onPress={signupFn}>Sign Up Page</Button>
            <Button title="login" onPress={loginFn}>Login Page</Button>
        </View>
    )
}
```

Upon pressing the login button I'm presented with this error:

```
Error: Exception in HostFunction: Malformed calls from JS: field sizes are different.

[[4,23,4,9,45,23],[0,1,4,0,6,0],[[],[93],[25,"setPressed",[false]],[],[94,100,1627731325208,false]],964]
```

The error only happened when I pass the email and password parameters as state variables. When I hard code my email and password into the `signInWithEmailAndPassword` function, the error goes away (but is obviously not a viable solution). Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it, I was using the `onChange` prop when I should've been using the [`onChangeText`](https://reactnative.dev/docs/textinput#onchangetext) prop to deal with state.